# Find a particular file in three different unix servers

Tags: shell, unix

Find a particular file in three different unix servers 
I 'm new in shell script , i tried this but it is not working

```
servers="server1 server2 server3"
for e in $servers
do

   ssh $e find /path/to/dir -type f -name -exec grep -i "WORD-TO-FIND" {} \; -print >$log
    echo " $log file."
done
```

Please help me with this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the WORD-TO-FIND that you use ? What is the value of the $log variable ?

Comment: Using `find path -type f -name "WORD_TO_FIND"` is much better?

Comment: I suspect that `-exec` is not the argument you want to pass to the `-name` option... And that throws off the rest of the command line as well...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve. Judging from your code I assume you want to search for files with a given name in a certain directory, and if they contain a certain string of text, then write the lines containing this text into a log file.

If that's the case, then the following should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
log=/var/tmp/filefind.log
servers="server1 server2 server3"
for e in $servers
do
  ssh $e "find /path/to/dir -type f -name file-names-to-consider -exec grep -i 'word-to-find' '{}' \;" >> $log
done
```

Or, if you would like to have written into the logfile the names of those files that contained the word you were looking for, and nothing else, then consider this solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
log=/var/tmp/filefind.log
servers="server1 server2 server3"
for e in $servers
do
  ssh $e "find /etc -type f -name file-names-to-consider -exec sh -c \"grep -i 'word-to-find' '{}' > /dev/null && echo '{}'\" \;" >> $log
done
```

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
log=/var/tmp/filefind.log
servers="server1 server2 server3"
for e in $servers
do
  ssh $e "find /etc -type f -name host* -exec sh -c \"grep -i '127' '{}' > /dev/null && echo '{}'\" \;" >> $log
done
```

will write into */var/tmp/filefind.log* the name of all files on the 3 servers that a) are located at */etc* or below, b) match the file name pattern of *host** (e.g. *hosts* or *hostname* but not *myhost*, and c) contain at least one line with the string *123*.

If, however, you simply want to check if the file */foo/bar* exists on the servers, and you would like to have the names of those servers that do have the file to be written to the log file, then this solution will do:

```
#!/bin/bash
log=/var/tmp/filefind.log
servers="server1 server2 server3"
filename=/foo/bar
for e in $servers
do
  ssh $e "test -f $filename && echo $e" >> $log
done
```